# Returning a specific column using prepared statement for MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, select, prepared-statement

I am trying to use a prepared statement for a MySQL for the first time, but it is not returning any data:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=[DBASE];host=localhost', '[USER]', '[PWORD]',
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));

$sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['myusername']) . '"');
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$user_id = $result->id;
```

As is probably clear I am trying to return the user_id for a given username.  Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: When people say "use PDO"... *that's not how*.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Erm, can you explain what you mean by this?  I was following a tutorial to construct this, so surely it can't be that far off?

Comment: [I think I'll let the documentation explain instead.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: If a tutorial had you write it that way, find a new tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to do:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=[DBASE];host=localhost', '[USER]', '[PWORD]',
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));

$sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?');

$success = $sth->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));

if ($success) {
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $user_id = $result->id;
} else {
    echo "Query failed.";
    var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
}
```

You have to prepare a statement using either named or positional parameters.  If the prepare was successful, you can then execute queries on that statement.  Depending on how you bound the parameters, execute will accept different types of arguments.

If the execution of the statement was successful, you can then read results from it.

More examples in the manual:

- [Prepared Statements and Stored Procedures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
- [`PDO::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
- [Complete PDO Reference](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: Thanks very much, that works well, though I had to add a closing bracket in the line `$success = $sth->execute(array($_SESSION['myusername']));`.  Thanks for the links too.

Comment: Fixed the answer, thanks for pointing that out.  Hopefully it gets you started, once you get the hang of PDO its pretty easy to use.